# Transmit data from smartwatch to smartphone over bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth, wear-os, android-bluetooth, wearables

I need some help for data transmission between Android Wear and Android phone.
I found some tutorials and sample code, so I could make a framework. 
Much of my code is similar to the Android open source sample, https://github.com/googlesamples/android-BluetoothChat.
But my question is, if devices are already paired, do I need them all?
In other words, my Android Wear watch and Android phone are already paired, can data transfer be much simpler? Or do each application using Bluetooth need everything from above sample code?
Anyone who has this kind of experience of knows useful samples, please help me!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: you will need to do the scan , because if you dont how you gonna launch an intent ? if the devices are paired there is no such logic to be made

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your devices are already paired you don't have to set up the Bluetooth connection yourself. You can simply use the [Data Layer API](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/accessing.html) to synchronize and send data between the wearable and the phone.

Comment: Thanks! I could make successful results using Data Layer API.

Comment: Will it still be possible to share via Bluetooth. I might wanna know what is Data Layer API is doing under the hood. In my case I wanna communicate through iOS.